# How To Show Postgres Tables With Perl

Tags: database, postgresql, perl

I have tried using the \d command inside perl and this is what i get

**DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "d"**

This is My Code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;

$myConnection = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=test;host=localhost","postgres", "pass123");

$query = $myConnection->prepare("\d");
$result = $query->execute();


while(my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
      print "ID = ". $row[0] . "\n";
}

$myConnection->disconnect();
```

Comment: A backslash has a special meaning in a double-quoted Perl string. Either escape the backslash (`"\\d"`) or use a single-quoted string (`'\d'`).

Comment: I would assume that `\d` is a command of the `psql` utility and not available as a SQL query via DBI.

Comment: i tried \\d and '\d' nothing works

Comment: What is a "*Postgres Tale*"?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and most portable way is to use the [`table_info`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#table_info) function.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the list of tables or views, you can use

```
my @tables = $dbh->tables();
```

You can also restrict the list to a specific schema. For example, to get only the tables in the `public` schema, without the `pg_catalog` and `information_schema` tables:

```
my @tables = $dbh->tables(undef, 'public');
```

See https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Pg#tables for details.

For more information about the tables, use `table_info` as suggested in [Laurenz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45236196/111036)